# Schema Error on Migration from SQL Server to MySQL using MySQL Workbench due to comma in values in particular tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to migrate the database from SQL Server to MySQL using MySQL Workbench(version- 6.3.8). But Workbench is creating new column whenever data in a column has a comma, in it.

Example:

```sql
Table: Testing

Insert into Testing(id,title,url,description)
values(1,'Reports,Revenue','default', 'Null');
```

It should directly import the table as it is but due to comma present in the values.
Its treating every comma seperated value in that column as seperate column value and lets say if table has two columns available its trying to insert 4 value and as there is difference in table structure its failing and it will skip the import of the whole table.

So please help me to solving this error via MySQL Workbench.

Comment: this inserrt code produces no eror , but as you didn't provide the CREATE TABLE for you table it ios har to guess, the  comma between Reports and Revenue are part of the string.